# Expand the AspNetUsers by adding an extra model - code first

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to update the AspNetUsers table and add custom properties. 
I made a new class called UserModel.

```
namespace theNotes.Models
{
 public class UserModel 
 {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Education Level")]
    public string Grade { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> TotalFilesDownloaded { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FilesDownloadedToday { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Money { get; set; }
 }
}
```

When I run the command `Add-Migration UserInfo` in the PM a class is made with the methods `up` and `down` are empty. Why is it not generating the information of this class?

EDIT: I am using the asp.net mvc internet application, and what I want to do is add these columns to the AspNetUsers table that is automatically generated.

Comment: Did you add the reference to your DBContext?

Comment: Where did you add this class? in the `Model` folder ?
If so , can you post the complete code of your class?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Asp.net Identity, then you should add new properties in class ApplicationUser or similar one, which inherits from IdentityUser.

Comment: You can always create a separate model and create a relationship with the `ApplicationUser` model. Adding properties is not the only option.

Comment: You are right, however extending "out of the box" class seems to be the fastest as well as the simplest solution.

Comment: I agree with that. Except it's not extensible.

Answer (score 0):

Few items are missing on your code:

- You need to inherit fro the `DBContext` add this to your code where your `UserModel` class is:

  `public class UserModelContext : DbContext
  {
      public DbSet<UserModel> UserModels{ get; set; }
  }`
- You need to run `enable-migrations` command for the new Context `UserModelContext`

  - Once you run the command you will get the error

> EntityType 'UserModel' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

so you need to redesign your table and add a key.

- You need to reference the foreign key to reference the User table

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your `UserModel` class like this:

```
[Table("AspNetUsers")]
public class UserModel : IdentityUser
{
   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "Education Level")]
   public string Grade { get; set; }

   public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
   public string IPAddress { get; set; }

   public Nullable<int> TotalFilesDownloaded { get; set; }
   public Nullable<int> FilesDownloadedToday { get; set; }
   public Nullable<decimal> Money { get; set; }
}
```